# Wordpress display first parent and its sub-menu only on sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a main navigation and all parents have children.
Example:
Parent Page A:

- Child A1
  - Child A11
  - Child A12
    - Child A12
  - Child A13
- Child A2
- Child A3

Parent Page B:

- Child B1
  - Child B11
  - Child B12
    - Child B12
  - Child B13
- Child B2

If we are click on Child A12, sidebar should looks like:
Parent Page A:

- Child A1
  - Child A11
  - Child A12
    - Child A12
  - Child A13
- Child A2
- Child A3

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to create custom widget for that...

Comment: No I want PHP template. Any php code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use vertical navigation menu like accordion, so look this to [jquery simple vertical menu](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-vertical-accordion-menu/) and on this base write your php code, also you can look on this example of [php menu](http://www.finalwebsites.com/tutorials/dynamic-navigation-list.php). When you will split this two examples I gues you will recieve that functionality that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/child-navigation/

It adds some arguments to wp_nav_menu()

This should do exactly what you want:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'my_menu_location',
    'children_only' => TRUE,
    'children_start_level' => 1,
    'children_show_start_level' => true,
) );
```